# GLIBC_2.25 not found when tyring using argon2 in nodejs

Tags: node.js, argon2-ffi

this is the response i got when i run node file

`node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1210
return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
^

Error: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /home/mhmd8/nodevenv/dad.online/16/lib/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi-v3/argon2.node) at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1210:18) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32) at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12) at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19) at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18) at Object.<anonymous> (/home/muhamad8/nodevenv/resumeku.online/16/lib/node_modules/argon2/argon2.js:9:25) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14) at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32) at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12) { code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED' }`

how i can solve this problem, thanks!